# html - how to dynamically change url of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Something that I notice Google Maps does is, if you move the canvas for the map around, or zoom in, or pretty much any action with your mouse, the actual URL in the URL bar changes accordingly, includng for example the center point for latitude and longitude.

How do you do this (I assume by JavaScript) without reloading the entire page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Adding # to your url wont refresh your page (example: www.somepage.com/index.html#page=about , changing to ...index.html#page=contact dynamicly wont refresh page. ) .And you can send parameters through url and change content of your page on url #change.

location.hash = '#myhash';